# Замена манифеста через библиотеку dnlib

Tags: c#, manifest, dnlib

Как можно изменить манифест другого приложения при помощи библиотеки [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib). Примеров я так и не нашёл.
Поэтому пробовал искать методы вручную (и их не оказалось) максимум что я понял что это можно как-то провернуть благодаря классу: [GenerateApplicationManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/generateapplicationmanifest-task?view=vs-2022) из `Microsoft.Build`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раз вы написали что методов у библиотеки нет, значит их нет, верно?

Comment: @aepot, я не все проверил, только часть. Возможно где-то что-то пропустил. Решил спросить тут, мб кто-то знает...